# Oracle 10g auto increment column with two tables

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am having two auto increment keys in two tables (`bill` and `detail`).

I set pk and fk for respective table columns.

Now I have to insert the data in both tables by using oracle forms.

bill table having single row but detail table having multiple row for single row in bill table.

Now how can I insert detail table data with the reference of bill table entry

Like this:

```
Bill:                         
1.Entry1                        
2.Entry2                           
3.Entry3                            


Detail:    
1: 1Sentry  
   2 bentry
   3 centry 

2: 1 entry
```

Comment: What is the problem? The reference to bill in detail is a foreign key, which is not generated by autoincrement. If detail has a primary key (generated by autoincrement), it plays no role in the dependency.

Comment: Is there any way to display auto incremented value in oracle?